# How do I track Em.Store dirtiness in ember.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to track the presence of dirty records in my Ember store.

I want to have a 'save' button with a linked property in order to disable the button whenever there are no records pending update.

I suppose there are a few ways to do this but I'm looking for the correct 'ember' way of doing things.

What is the easiest approach here? AFAICS I can..

- Manually set a global property whenever a property is changed - and reset it whenever the store is synced to the server
- Have a property on my controller which is calculated based on the contents of the store. I was able to do this like so But I found that the property did not update when the store was updated.

...

```
hasUpdates: function() {
    console.log('hej!')
    return (this.get('store').get('defaultTransaction.buckets.updated.list.length') > 0);
}.property('store')
```

This must be a common pattern - how do I do this?

Edit: Will keep answer updated with things that dont work

```
  hasUpdates: function() {
    console.log('hej!');
    return (this.get('store').get('defaultTransaction.buckets.updated.list.length') > 0);
  }.property('store._recordsToSave@each')
```

Comment: FYI the buckets are Ember.OrderedSets, which are NOT Ember.Objects and are not observable. Unfortunately, at present it doesn't seem to be possible to get the "status" of a Transaction, at all... it's pretty bare bones :/ I don't know if that's intentional, but it is highly annoying. I've needed to do much the same thing as you several times and each time ended up hacking it into my array controllers. Not ideal at all.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - seems to be something that quite a few people have recognised as a common use pattern (and one not supported by ember-data at this time) - I'd raise a github issue but there are already quite alot for ember-data. I'll see if I can get any further suggestions on irc

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with one record at a time, you can always bind to the model's `isDirty` property. I usually create a computed property called `isClean` on the controller that is a negation of `isDirty`, then in the template

```
<input type="submit" {{bindAttr disabled="isClean"}}>
```

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to avoid having to implement this - but I've kind of run out of ideas and will probably end up doing this... My main issue is that the model in question and the controller are not close to each other in the application. It will involve some pollution of unrelated controllers but that's maybe what I'll have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you:

#### Initialize the app

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

DS.Model.reopenClass({
  dirtyItems: function(){
    return this.filter(function(model) { 
      return model.get('isDirty'); 
    }).get('content');
  }
});

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Product.FIXTURES = [{id: 1, name: 'Table'}]
```

#### Then try

```
App.Product.dirtyItems(); // -> return []

book = App.Product.createRecord({name: 'Book'});
App.Product.dirtyItems(); // -> return [Object]

book.save()
App.Product.dirtyItems(); // -> return []

skate = App.Product.createRecord({name: 'Skate'});
bike = App.Product.createRecord({name: 'Bike'});
App.Product.dirtyItems(); // -> return [Object, Object]

skate.get('store').save()
App.Product.dirtyItems(); // -> return []
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this. I've actually abandoned ember for the time being - I don't have the time to work through all the issues I encountered. I'll pick it up again in the future though for sure.